# hover link info

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, hyperlink, hover

how can i get the effect that when u point over a link an information is shown in a box which tells u what that link does.

its like when you hover over a link a box explains its action.

Can some1 help me out with a neat sample.

do i need to use the ajax - hovermenuextender for this??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how fancy you want to be. I personally have found jQuery (AKA JavaScript) to answer the call here. [qTip is a jQuery library](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) that has some amazing pop-up "bubble" effects. Head over to their website and check out the various things you can do.

If you head to the [qTip documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/) (particularly [this page](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#replace)), you can see how easy it is to replace "normal" link pop-ups with a much better looking tool tip. Code example shown below:

```
$('a[title]').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true } })
```

Comment: +1 for recommending qtip.  one of the easiest jquery plugins ever.

Comment: Looks interesting; proceeding to download and test! Thanks!

Comment: @miyamotogL - No problem. Remember that you'll need jQuery, too @ jQuery.com.

Comment: is this free to use in a GUI... is there any royalty??

Comment: @user175084 - Per the download page on the site: "qTip is licensed under the open source MIT license, which allows you to use the script for whatever you want, whenever you want, however you want, as long as you include a copy of the license!" - No royalties required.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ASP.NET you could use [ASPNET ToolTip](http://www.aspnettooltip.com/aspnettooltip_Demonstration.aspx); hover over the bulleted items in the link to see examples.

Comment: this is not free.. i cant believe AJAX does not have a tool tip.. for this